# Junit test classes compile error in java 11?

Tags: maven, junit, maven-plugin, java-11, javacompiler

I am migrating to Java 11 from Java 8. I am getting compile error when doing Maven build.

```
    src
       main
           com
              A.class
    
       test
          com
            Atest.class
 Atest.java {
  A a;//compile error

}
```

Have used plugin in `pom.xml`:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

am getting error like:

```
[ERROR]   symbol:   class A
[ERROR]   location: class com.Atest
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile)
on project 'ourproject': Compilation failure
```

I have tried adding `<release>11</release>`  ...but still getting same error.
Anything do we need to add in pom file extra to compile for test classes?

Comment: Please show the source code of the class and the full error message

Comment: Where have you located the java source files `A.java` and `aTest.java`?

Answer (score 0):

1. The standard directories for Java main and test classes are `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`, not just `src/main` and `src/test`, see [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

2. In these dirs are Java source files (`*.java`) not compiled class files (`*.class`).
3. Why declaring `<executions>` on the compiler plugin? See [Configuring Your Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/usage.html#Configuring_Your_Compiler_Plugin):

> Since the Compiler Plugin executes automatically during their phases, you don't have to put `executions` unlike many other plugins.

4. See [Maven Surefire Plugin / Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html):

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - ...
> - `"**/*Test.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".

I'm not sure whether `Atest.java` is covered by this.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. i have tried the same...its not working in java 11...there is no issue with java 8.